# Relation between the size of key space and message for an encryption scheme that is not perfectly secure

Tags: encryption, perfect-secrecy

I have been trying to solve the following:
Given a scheme that is perfectly correct but not perfect secrecy. It satisfies computational security, however, in that, if Q = Pr[Adv wins no query semantic security game], then

$$Pr[Q] \leq \frac{1}{2} + \epsilon$$
for some negligible $\epsilon$ in $n$ which is the security parameter.

What should be the relation between the key space and message space? I have concluded that they do not necessarily need to have a relation like $|K| \leq |M|$ as it is possible to prove using a counterexample that this is not the case. So the key space can be larger or smaller than the message space.

I tried using the following implication:

$$(perfect security) => (|K| >= |M|) \\
(|K| < |M|) => (! perfect security) [contrapositive]$$

But this does not give me a meaningful relationship as I want the converse of the contrapositive to state something about their relationship.

I want to find a relation between $|K|$ and $|M|$ in terms of $\epsilon$.

Am I on the right track? Kindly help me come up with a mathematical construction for the same.

Comment: What do you understand for negligible $\epsilon$? Negligible w.r.t. what variable? I think your assumptions are missing something - right now the identity function (with key space of size 0) would be fine - since you did not specify your epsilon or what computational security means

Comment: @tylo I am assuming it to be a negligible function of the security paramter n which may be the size of the key in this case.

Comment: This "may" might be part of the reason why you're not getting to a proper proof. Challenge yourself with trivial things, e.g. would the identity function or a Caesar cipher work here? Even assuming a negligible function might be ... off. You are looking for a symmetric scheme, but negligible functions most often play a role in proving asymmetric cryptography. The tools might not fit the problem at hand.